# Can I specify what fields I want to receive from query when using HandlerSockets?

Tags: php, mysql, nosql, handlersocket

Can I specify what fields I want to receive from query when using [HandlerSockets](https://github.com/DeNADev/HandlerSocket-Plugin-for-MySQL) ?

Here is my sample table

```
CREATE TABLE pushed_media
(
    user_id BINARY(12) NOT NULL,
    story_id BINARY(12) NOT NULL,
    sent_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( user_id, story_id )
);
```

Php code that queries it is below

```
$hs = new HandlerSocket($host, $port);
if (!($hs->openIndex(1, $dbname, $table, HandlerSocket::PRIMARY, 'user_id,story_id,sent_date')))
{
    echo $hs->getError(), PHP_EOL;
    die();
}

$user_id = pack('H*', substr(md5('ruslan'), 0, 24));
$story_id = pack('H*', substr(md5('story1'), 0, 24));

$retval = $hs->executeSingle(1, '=', array($user_id, $story_id), 1, 0);
```

All I need is `sent_date` because I already know two other values. Is it possible to not to transfer them over the network again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the fields that you want to receive from the query by simply specifying them in the `field` parameter of the [openIndex](https://code.google.com/p/php-handlersocket/wiki/HandlerSocketOpenIndex) method.
As you can read [here](http://code.google.com/p/php-handlersocket/wiki/HandlerSocketExecuteSingle), this code:

```
<?php
$hs->openIndex(1, 'db', 'table', 'PRIMARY', 'k,v');
$ret = $hs->executeSingle(1, '>=', array('K1'));
var_dump($ret);
?>
```

Is equivalent to the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT k,v FROM table WHERE k >= 'K1' LIMIT 1
```

Back to your example, if you want to read only the `sent_date` field value:

```
$hs = new HandlerSocket($host, $port);
if (!$hs->openIndex(1, $dbname, $table, myHandlerSocket::PRIMARY, 'sent_date')) {
    die($hs->getError());
}

$user_id  = pack('H*', substr(md5('ruslan'), 0, 24));
$story_id = pack('H*', substr(md5('story1'), 0, 24));

$retval = $hs->executeSingle(1, '=', array($user_id, $story_id), 1, 0);
die("<pre>".print_r($retval,true)."</pre>");
```

The resulting output should be something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2013-02-01 22:18:39
)
```

The [HandlerSocket protocol documentation](https://github.com/DeNADev/HandlerSocket-Plugin-for-MySQL/blob/master/docs-en/protocol.en.txt) states:

> Once an 'open_index' request is issued, the HandlerSocket plugin opens
>   the specified index and keep it open until the client connection is
>   closed. Each open index is identified by <indexid>. If <indexid> is
>   already open, the old open index is closed. **You can open the same
>   combination of <dbname> <tablename> <indexname> multple times,
>   possibly with different <columns>.** For efficiency, keep <indexid>
>   small as far as possible.

Comment: So usage of `openIndex` actually doesn't mean I have to have an index on this column?

Comment: @ruslan Yes, in the openIndex call you specify the index to use and which fields you want to read, while in the executeSingle call you specify the index column values to fetch. See updated answer for further details about the openIndex call.

Answer (score 0):

What about `executeMulti` ?

```
$retval = $hs->executeMulti(array(
  array(1, '=', array($user_id), 1, 0),
  array(2, '=', array($story_id), 1, 0),
));
```